# Background-color transition doesn't work

Tags: html, css, transition, background-color

I have an issue with the background-color transition: If I define the object's background in CSS and then add the transition to it, it works well, but if I do the same in HTML, I does nothing... The codes are:

```css
.container a {
  background-color: #333;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.container a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Login</a>
  <!-- This works well-->
  <a href="#" style="background-color: green">Login</a>
  <!-- This does not-->
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline styles have the highest [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), so your rule isn't being applied. You can get around that by not using inline styles, or applying the dreaded `!important` to the rule

```css
.container a {
  background-color: #333;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.container a:hover {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Login</a>
  <!-- This works well-->
  <a href="#" style="background-color: green">Login</a>
  <!-- This does not-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well! I will accept this answer as soon as I can!